# Object has no method 'setupState'

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I serialized my canvas using the `canvas.toJSON()` method. But trying to recreate my canvas, results in the objects being redrawn, but being 100% unresponsive (cannot drag around).

I tried to be clever and tried redrawing the objects 1 by 1 by extracting them from the JSON (pseudocode of what I am doing below).

```
forEach(jsonRepresentation.objects, function (obj) {
            canvas.add(obj);
}
canvas.renderAll();
```

This also does not work and leads the objects to NOT draw but clicking on the CANVAS results in the error:

`TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'setupState'`

Any idea of what could be happening?

The application is very complex, so I am not sure a fiddle/plunkr could be possible.

The objects DO have custom attributes, but I made sure modify the `toObject` method prototype as follows:

```
    fabric.Object.prototype.toObject = (function (toObject) {
      return function () {
        return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
          customAttribute1: this.customAttribute1,
          ...
        });
      };
    })(fabric.Object.prototype.toObject)
```

In order for those attributes to be persisted (which they are after a manual scanning of the resulting JSON).

UPDATE:

I noticed that the issue arises since a lot of my objects have objects inside of them that are not being recursively parsed to the FabricJS canvas format. I will continue to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a somewhat similar problem. In my application I did not want to save the complete canvas, but only some objects added by the user. The objects' methods are not represented in JSON, just variables (`width`, `height`,...) - so when trying to redraw the objects in the canvas, I (probably you too) got the mentioned error.

I solved this by recreating the objects based on those variables, that made it into the JSON representation. In my application the FabricJS-data was stored as `geometry` besides some additional data (`id`, `metadata`).

```
for(var primitiveKey in data[0].value.primitives){
  var currentPrimitive = data[0].value.primitives[primitiveKey];
  var reassembledPrimitive = [];

  reassembledPrimitive.id = currentPrimitive.id;
  reassembledPrimitive.metadata = currentPrimitive.metadata;
  reassembledPrimitive.geometry = new Fabric.Rect(currentPrimitive.geometry);
  this.primitiveList.push(reassembledPrimitive);
}
```

Drawing the primitives:

```
redrawImage:function(){
  this.canvas.add(this.image);
  for(var i = 0; i < this.primitives.length; i++){      
    this.canvas.add(this.primitives[i].geometry);
  }
}
```

If using different object types, you would have to read each object's `type` and instantiate accordingly.

The solution is not very pretty, let me know if you already found another and better one.

Cheers,
smon